# How to tell Eclipse not include project reference, instead get JAR for custom dependency in local repo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two libraries which are built with Maven, and then installed into the local repo.

In my application, I'm using these two libraries and so I reference them in my pom in standard way:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-google-drive-manager</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>PdfBoxUtils</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version
</dependency>
```

Two libs are PdfBoxUtils and simple-google-drive-manager

In Eclipse, under Maven Dependencies, most things are listed as `artifactId-version.jar` as expected. But for the custom libraries I made, Eclipse recognizes they are in same workspace and instead of including jar, includes the project itself.

[image]

I don't want this! It's confusing, and I want to be able to force this project to use the locally installed library, not just whatever is currently in the library project's source.

How do I get eclipse to *actually* use the JAR from local repo rather than referencing local proejct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select Maven->Disable Workspace resolution in context menu of the project.

Comment: why would anyone want to enable workspace resolution? why use Maven to specify version if it's just going to use project's source? This drove me mad -- I made some changed to my libraries, a bug fix. I forgot to install it to the local repo after the changes. But the project using the libs did not fail because it was pulling from the project source. So I thought Maven had the updated bug-fix version! I packaged and deployed, it grabbed the older version in local repo -- and it failed. It took me a while to realize what was going on...

Comment: if you want to use that workflow you are probably better of using release versions of your libraries in dependencies and snapshot versions in project poms.

Comment: "release versions of libs in dependencies and snapshot versions in project poms" -- I'm not quite following you. For project A using lib B, you're saying I should package/install B in repo as a 1.0-SNAPSHOT as it's developed, and then in project A just keep the <dependency></dependency> referencing 1.0-SNAPSHOT? I was concerned that lib B would not override previous version if I didn't change version number from say 1.0-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.0 but I suppose that's not the case?

Comment: Nice, I want the opposite to refer other projects and not from jars. how to do that? What is the default nature?

Comment: @Jay - I imagine you already tried... but is there `Maven -> Enable Workspace Resolution` ?

Comment: @mmcrae Thanks mate. Yes I could see that option 'Maven -> Enable Workspace Resolution'. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a maven project, which can be done with ->Configure->Convert to Maven Project. Then add an entry for your local repo into your pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

After that, you need to use Maven install:install-file to copy the jar and associated .pom into the repository.

Finally, of course, add a dependency for the file to your pom.

Comment: on my machine the .m2 repository is /home/ubuntu/.m2/repository -- thus my <url> should read `<url>file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository</ur>` is that right?

Comment: thank you for your help but I don't think this was needed for me. I think Maven will check the local repo automatically

Comment: Oh, yea, different question.